# PHP, SQL. Arrange worker / hostess working shift in 7 days / weekly view timetable. Where first column is current date

Tags: php, sql

Currently I'm doing hostess booking system. Whenever a customer book it'll be displayed at scheduled.php.

My problem is that:
 1. The name of a host keep repeating, I just want I appear once in a row. 
 2. And instead of populating a row horizontally. It populate the table
    vertically.
 3.

This is data in database. idtime is primary key in timesheet table. idemp is foreign key from employee table.
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaFcW.png)

This is my current code:

```html
<?php
// Include config file
require_once "config.php";

// Part for <th> on table
// today date
$datenow = date('d-m-y');
$daynow = date('l');
// Next date and day from current date
$date1 = date('d-m-y', strtotime("+1 day"));
$day1 = date('l', strtotime("+1 day"));
// Next 2 date and day from current date
$date2 = date('d-m-y', strtotime("+2 day"));
$day2 = date('l', strtotime("+2 day"));
// Next 3 date and day from current date
$date3 = date('d-m-y', strtotime("+3 day"));
$day3 = date('l', strtotime("+3 day"));
// Next 4 date and day from current date
$date4 = date('d-m-y', strtotime("+4 day"));
$day4 = date('l', strtotime("+4 day"));
// Next 5 date and day from current date
$date5 = date('d-m-y', strtotime("+5 day"));
$day5 = date('l', strtotime("+5 day"));
// Next 6 date and day from current date
$date6 = date('d-m-y', strtotime("+6 day"));
$day6 = date('l', strtotime("+6 day"));
    
// SQL for to fetch data from database
$time = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE date_time <= CURDATE() + 6");
    
$time1 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM timesheet WHERE date_time = CURDATE() + 1");



mysqli_close($link);
?>

<div style="text-align: center;">
    <a href="addshift.php" class="btn btn-success">Addshift</a>
</div>    

<br><br>

<section>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Host</th>
                    <th><?php echo $daynow . "<br>" . $datenow; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $day1 . "<br>" . $date1; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $day2 . "<br>" . $date2; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $day3 . "<br>" . $date3; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $day4 . "<br>" . $date4; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $day5 . "<br>" . $date5; ?></th>
                    <th><?php echo $day6 . "<br>" . $date6; ?></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                
                <?php while($empTime = mysqli_fetch_assoc($time)) { ?>
                <tr>
                    
                    <td><?php echo $empTime ['namekanji']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $empTime ['start_time']; echo " - "; echo $empTime ['end_time']; ?></td>
                    
                    
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is what my code display: [View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsR2t.png)

This is what I wanted, not everyday the host is booked. Some day they didn't have to work:
[View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOWGe.png)

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Have you tried to normalize all your tables to reduce data redundancy?

Comment: I don't think I do any normalization. And I'm not quite so sure about it also. But, I checked https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html  And I think, I know what it means. I'll try to normalize my table.

Comment: If you can refactor your query to use PDO instead of mysqli. It is a common practice now to use PDO though it requires you to learn and understand it first but trust me, its worth the while.